# subprocess command fails when run in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, subprocess, jupyter

this works in the interpreter

```
python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])
[sudo] password for stefan: 
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39  InRelease
.
.
.
etched 2,778 kB in 1s (2,305 kB/s)                                                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
12 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
0
>>> exit()
```

but if i put it in a cell in jupyter, I get this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])


output: 1


subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])


CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-33ce645708e7> in <module>()
----> 1 subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    188         if cmd is None:
    189             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 190         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    191     return 0
    192 

CalledProcessError: Command '['sudo', 'apt', 'update']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Using something like `check_output()` instead of `check_call()` will return to you the error string and be more descriptive. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: Is the jupyter process running with `sudo` privileges?

Comment: OF course, you're right stacks on stacks! That would be a major security hole if jupyter allowed privilege escalation.  When jupyter is run as root - no problem. thank you.